# Writing a python dict into excel

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have an extremely long python dict with some keys with more dicts inside like the example below

```
{
       "dscpTagValue": {"data": 10,
                        "accuracy": Low Drop"}
       "description": "Latency Insensitive"
}
,
{
       "dscpTagValue": {"data": 10,
                        "accuracy": Low Drop"}
       "description": "Latency Insensitive"
}
{
       "dscpTagValue": {"data": 10,
                        "accuracy": Low Drop"}
       "description": "Latency Insensitive"
}
```

How would I export this into excel?, some dicts could have several dictionaries inside, some dicts could have no other dicts inside just keys and values..

Comment: This looks more like a list of Python Dicts. Can you ensure the format of the input displayed here corresponds with your data? Or rather, please provide an input we can play with that is descriptive enough (with dicts without other dicts inside, with dicts with other dicts inside, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the data to be a list of dictionaries, you can use `csv.DictWriter()` and specify the column names of the csv with the maximum keys. Something like this:

```py
data = [
        {
            "dscpTagValue": {"data": 10, "accuracy": "Low Drop"},
            "description": "Latency Insensitive"
        },
        .
        .
        .
]

import csv

len_keys = [len(d.keys()) for d in data] # no. of keys of each dictionary
csv_columns = list(data[np.argmax(len_keys)]) # csv column headers == longest dict (keys)

try:
    with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for d in data:
            writer.writerow(d)
except IOError:
    print('IOError')
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you to use `pandas` for these data management operations. Using a list of dictionaries such as:

```
l = [{'dscpTagValue': {'data': 10, 'accuracy': 'Low Drop'},
  'description': 'Latency Insensitive'},
 {'dscpTagValue': {'data': 9, 'accuracy': 'Low Drop'},
  'description': 'Latency Insensitive'},
 {'dscpTagValue': {'data': 8, 'accuracy': 'Medium Drop'},
  'description': 'Latency Sensitive'}]
```

You can write it into an excel using `to_excel` of a pandas Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
print(df.to_string())
#                             dscpTagValue          description
#0    {'data': 10, 'accuracy': 'Low Drop'}  Latency Insensitive
#1     {'data': 9, 'accuracy': 'Low Drop'}  Latency Insensitive
#2  {'data': 8, 'accuracy': 'Medium Drop'}    Latency Sensitive

df.to_excel("my_excel_file.xlsx", sheet_name='my sheet name')
```